# AngularJS Rails User Sign Up without Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, user-registration

I am trying to create a sign up flow with Angular client sending user inputs to the server via the $resource service. The User model on the Rails side has a has_secure_password, password_digest field on the model.

Problem is:
(1) Rails sends error to Angular client that "password is missing" even though it is not.
(2) Password and confirmation seem to not be getting sent by Angular?
(3) Password digest is not getting set, remains "nil".

(1) Rails sends error to Angular client that "password is missing" even though it is not.

```
 Object { username: "testuser", first_name: "Test", last_name: "User", email: "test@sample.com", password: "password5375", password_confirmation: "password5375" } main.js:157
Object { data: Object, status: 422, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: " " } main.js:163
"password:can't be blank"
```

(2) Note that the password & confirmation aren't included in the wrapped "user" hash

```
Started POST "/api/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-04 19:04:46 -0400
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"username"=>"user3", "first_name"=>"Uss", "last_name"=>"ErThree", "email"=>"user3@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"username"=>"user3", "first_name"=>"Uss", "last_name"=>"ErThree", "email"=>"user3@example.com"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user3@example.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'user3' LIMIT 1
  SQL (164.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 04 Oct 2014 23:04:46 UTC +00:00], ["email", "user3@example.com"], ["first_name", "Uss"], ["last_name", "ErThree"], ["updated_at", Sat, 04 Oct 2014 23:04:46 UTC +00:00], ["username", "user3"]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
```

(3) From the console, note that the password digest is not getting set.

```
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 3, created_at: "2014-10-04 23:04:46", updated_at: "2014-10-04 23:04:46", username: "user3", first_name: "Uss", last_name: "ErThree", email: "user3@example.com", password_digest: nil>
1.9.3-p362 :010 > User.last.password_digest
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil



app.factory('User', function($resource){
  function User() {
    this.service = $resource('/api/users/:id.json', {id: '@id'},
      {
        'update': {method: 'PUT'},
        'show': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
      }
    );
  }



 User.prototype.all = function() {
    return this.service.query();
  };

  User.prototype.destroy = function(uid) {
    return this.service.remove({id: uid});
  }; 

  User.prototype.create = function(attributes) {
    return this.service.save(attributes);
  };

  User.prototype.update = function(attributes) {
    return this.service.update(attributes);
  };    

  User.prototype.show = function(uid) {
    return this.service.show({id: uid});
  }

  return new User;
});

    app.controller('UsersCreateCtrl', function($scope, User){
  $scope.createUser = function(){
    $scope.user;
    console.log($scope.user);
    var newUser = User.create($scope.user).$promise.then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.users.push(newUser);
        $scope.user = {};
    }, function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        angular.forEach(msg.data.errors, function(type, error){
            console.log(error + ":" + type);
        });
    });
  };
});

<h4>Register</h4>
<div ng-controller="UsersCreateCtrl">
  <form name="form" ng-submit="createUser()" novalidate>
    Name: <input name="username" type="text" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="username"/>
    First Name: <input name="first_name" type="text" ng-model="user.first_name" placeholder="first name" />
    Last Name: <input name="last_name" type="text" ng-model="user.last_name" placeholder="last name" />
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="email" />
    Password: <input name="password" type="text" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="password" />
    Confirm Password: <input name="password_confirmation" type="text" ng-model="user.password_confirmation" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT: Rails UsersController Posted**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

def index
    respond_with User.all
end

def create
    respond_with User.create(user_params)
end

def destroy
    respond_with User.destroy(params[:id])
end

def show 
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    respond_with User.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(source_params)
end

private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

end

Comment: post your rails controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your rails controller is not allowing password & password confirmation to be passed to the model due to not permitting them in the strong parameters.  Either that or you are not including them in the json user object being posted.  Since you are most likely doing User.create!(params[:user]), you need to make sure that you have permitted all the params you are expecting:

```
permitted_params = params[:user].permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
User.create!(permitted_params)
```

Comment: I am permitting password & password confirmation to be passed to the model  via strong params. My controller is posted. Thanks for your help. cc: @user2936314

Comment: what does your browser's web inspector show for the network data being posted to your create action?  Clearly somehow password & password confirmation are not ending up inside your params[:user] hash, which is your problem...

Comment: Here's what I see in the network data- Request Payload: {"username":"TheCatFelix","first_name":"TheCat","last_name":"Felix","email":"felixthecat@thecat.com","password":"password53","password_confirmation":"password53"}

Comment: Also, I am NOT using Devise. I plan to use Token authentication as described here http://blog.envylabs.com/post/75521798481/token-based-authentication-in-rails.

Comment: and can you post what user_params returns in your controller as well as what params is?

Comment: Are you asking what user_params is in my controller?             def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

Comment: no I meant, inspect the value returned from that as well as params.  Either Rails.logger.info(params); Rails.logger.info(user_params), or use something like pry / ruby debugger to see the output

Comment: From logger in UsersController's :create action                      New user: {"id"=>10, "created_at"=>Sun, 05 Oct 2014 03:59:25 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sun, 05 Oct 2014 03:59:25 UTC +00:00, "username"=>"faxonjetson", "first_name"=>"Fax", "last_name"=>"Jetson", "email"=>"faxjets@sample.com", "password_digest"=>nil, "password_salt"=>nil}

Comment: And here are the params being sent by Angular:            Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"username"=>"faxonjetson", "first_name"=>"Fax", "last_name"=>"Jetson", "email"=>"faxjets@sample.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"username"=>"faxonjetson", "first_name"=>"Fax", "last_name"=>"Jetson", "email"=>"faxjets@sample.com"}}

Comment: the object you logged from the controller has password_digest and password_salt... Where are those coming from if you are posting password and password_confirmation from angular?  Also, I assume you were logging the value returned from your user_params method-- can you show me the params object?

Comment: password_digest is a part of has_secure_password (on my User model). I removed password_salt

Comment: Here are the user_params and params object: New user: {"id"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "username"=>"FelCats", "first_name"=>"Fels", "last_name"=>"Cats", "email"=>"felscats@sample.com", "password_digest"=>nil}
Params: {"username"=>"FelCats", "first_name"=>"Fels", "last_name"=>"Cats", "email"=>"felscats@sample.com", "password"=>"password53", "password_confirmation"=>"password53", "format"=>"json", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"users", "user"=>{"username"=>"FelCats", "first_name"=>"Fels", "last_name"=>"Cats", "email"=>"felscats@sample.com"}}

Comment: I think your problem is you are posting your json payload with top level attributes.  Try changing your service to do:  return this.service.save({user: attributes});